# showing ip address from arraylist to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, arraylist, listbox

I'm looking for a code to show a list of ip address in a listbox. Here is what I came up with but there is a problem.

```
    private ArrayList twoNetwork()
    {

        ArrayList addresses = new ArrayList();

        string[] stringArray = firstAddressTB.Text.Split('.');

        byte[] Ip = stringArray.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();

        Ip[3] = 0;

         addresses.Add(Ip);            
         tableauIp[3] += 1;
         addresses.Add(Ip);

        return addresses;
    }
```

here I'm trying to make an arraylist of let's say 192.168.0.0 and add 192.168.0.1 . The problem with my code is that the arraylist will be 192.168.0.1 for both entry. I want to show both 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.1 in my listbox.

Comment: It is obvious from line Ip[3] = 0, question is not clear

Comment: Never use `ArrayList`. Use `List<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two instances of arrays and add them to ArrayList, otherwise, you end up with updating and adding the same instance twice.

```
private ArrayList twoNetwork()
    {
        ArrayList addresses = new ArrayList();
        string[] stringArray = firstAddressTB.Text.Split('.');
        addresses.Add(stringArray.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray()); 
        addresses.Add(stringArray.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray()); 
        addresses[0][3] = 0;
        addresses[1][3] = 1;
        return addresses;
    }
```

Comment: thx worked something out of your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Your code need little correction as below, ArrayList is declared in that Private method so your variable scope would be in that scope only. Please change accordingly.

```
ArrayList addresses = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList twoNetwork()
{

    string[] stringArray = firstAddressTB.Text.Split('.');

    byte[] Ip = stringArray.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();

    Ip[3] = 0;

     addresses.Add(Ip);            
     tableauIp[3] += 1;
     addresses.Add(Ip);

    return addresses;
}
```

Comment: thx thats a good point